# Is there a way to do custom /say commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've looked it up, and apparently there is not a way to. But, there's an NPC in my map where I have it "talking" with a `/say` command. So, is there a way to make it say something like `[(NPC Name)] (Text)` without mods?

Comment: `/say [Bob]: Hello there`?

Comment: You could try `/tellraw` or renaming command blocks? As for `/execute` on a named mob... Not sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A follow up on @Eisler485's answer:

The difference between `/say` and `/tellraw` when trying to do the same output:

[image: <code>/say</code>]

[image: <code>/tellraw</code>]

Remember that `/tellraw` has a lot of customisations. Just use data tags like `"color":"dark_red"` or `"bold":"true"`.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
/tellraw @a {text:"Insert Text Here"}
```

If you run this command the `@a` runs the command for every player and they will all see the message "Insert Text Here" in the chat.

You can edit the text color by using this command

```
/tellraw @a {"text": "This Text Is Now Green", "color": "green"}
```

Now the text "This Text Is Now Green" will show up on every players' Screen in a green text.

You can make the text as long as you want it.

Answer (score 5):

Rename the command block in an anvil.

If you name it "Bob" and give it the command `/say "hello"` it should come up as

> [Bob] Hello